# Horizontal scroll left doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I would like when i click on button , the `div` scroll to specified area.
for first click all things is ok.but for second click and more , the scroll animataion
doesn't work or work with much delays !
This is my jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/AliN11/7CgFp/3/

note: when opening jsfidde please scroll little horizontal  scroll in result section of my jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your javascript like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#b1").click(function(){$("#main").animate({ scrollLeft:110 }, "fast");});
        $("#b2").click(function(){$("#main").animate({ scrollLeft:210 }, "fast");});
        $("#b3").click(function(){$("#main").animate({ scrollLeft:310 }, "fast");});
        $("#b4").click(function(){$("#main").animate({ scrollLeft:410 }, "fast");});

    });
```

Comment: Like.Best answer ! :*

Answer (score 2):

You're appending a new click handler every time the window scrolls. This is not what you want. Just append the click handlers once and be done with it.

```
$("#b1").click(function(){$("#main").animate({ scrollLeft:110 }, "fast");});
$("#b2").click(function(){$("#main").animate({ scrollLeft:210 }, "fast");});
$("#b3").click(function(){$("#main").animate({ scrollLeft:310 }, "fast");});
$("#b4").click(function(){$("#main").animate({ scrollLeft:410 }, "fast");});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7CgFp/4/

Comment: Ah, darn, you  beat me to it :P